# Golang: Returning array at http response in Gin framework doesn't work

Tags: go

I am trying to return array []Employee as a response. Is has len 2.  But postman shows that responses body is empty.

```
type People struct {
    Height         int32          `json:"height" binding:"required"`
        Weight         int32          `json:"weight" binding:"required"`
}

type Employee struct {
    Salary int `json:"salary"`
    People
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, employeeArray)
```

I found in google that golang has some porblems with inner Binding structures.

UPD: code with MarshalJSON overriding. Here is the porblem

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

type TypeName struct {
    Name string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
}

func (p TypeName) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte("Joe"), nil
}

type People struct {
    Height int32 `json:"height" binding:"required"`
    Weight int32 `json:"weight" binding:"required"`
    TypeName
}

type Employee struct {
    Salary int `json:"salary"`
    People
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/employees", func(c *gin.Context) {
        employeeArray := []Employee{
            {
                Salary: 10000,
                People: People{
                    Height: 170,
                    Weight: 80,
                },
            },
            {
                Salary: 20000,
                People: People{
                    Height: 175,
                    Weight: 80,
                },
            },
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, employeeArray)
    })
    _ = r.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> func (p TypeName) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
>     return []byte("Joe"), nil
> }
> ```

`[]byte("Joe")` is not a valid json. It should be quoted. If you pay attention to the log of gin, you should see an error message there: `Error #01: json: error calling MarshalJSON for type main.Employee: invalid character 'J' looking for beginning of value`. This one should work:

```
func (p TypeName) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`"Joe"`), nil
}
```

And here is a demo for `time.Time`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Time struct {
    StandardTime time.Time
}

func (p Time) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    timeString := p.StandardTime.Format(time.RFC3339)
    return json.Marshal(timeString)
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/time", func(c *gin.Context) {
        timeArray := []Time{
            {
                StandardTime: time.Now(),
            },
            {
                StandardTime: time.Now().Add(30 * time.Minute),
            },
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, timeArray)
    })
    _ = r.Run()
}
```

Comment: Provably i understood the problem. Yeah, i have more complicated structure that the sample above. One of the field is|
 type Time struct {
 StandardTime time.Time
}

and i overrided Marshal func 
func (p Time) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
 timeString := p.StandardTime.Format(time.RFC3339)
 return []byte(timeString), nil
}

Comment: It's hard to read code in comment. Can you update your question to show that? A minimal demo would be more helpful.

Comment: done. So i have a custom structure inside, and i overrided MarshalJSON method for that

Comment: `Joe` is not a valid json, it should be quoted. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, quotes is the solution. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! BTW, if you pay attention to the log of gin, you should see an error message there: `Error #01: json: error calling MarshalJSON for type main.Employee: invalid character 'J' looking for beginning of value`.

Comment: I see, but i am a beginner at go. I have been learning it for 1 mouth after work.

Comment: Understood. There are some corner cases to handle if you return `[]byte` directly. So I have updated the demo to call `json.Marshal` to marshal a string.